# Why does <value>!0</value> match a default value of 0?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to set up a `.pom` file that will use one plugin if `forkCount` is 0, and a different plugin otherwise.  Furthermore, I want 0 to be the default value.  In other words, I want

`mvn run_tests` and `mvn -DforkCount=0 run_tests` to both use plugin "A", where `mvn run_tests -DforkCount=5` will use plugin "B".

I have a .pom file with the following segments:

```
<project ...>
   ...
   <properties>
      <forkCount>0</forkCount>
   </properties>
   ...
   <profiles>
      <profile>
          <!-- if forkCount==0, don't invoke any of the parallel execution configuration -->
          <id>no-parallel-execution</id>
          <activation>
             <property>
               <name>forkCount</name>
               <value>0</value>
             </property>
          </activation>
          <build>
             <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <! --- nothing in here references forkCount --> 
               </plugin>
             </plugins>
          </build>
      </profile>
    <profile>
    <profile>
       <!-- forkCount!=0, use the parallel execution configuration -->
       <id>parallel-execution</id>
       <activation>
          <property>
             <name>forkCount</name>
             <value>!0</value>
          </property>
       </activation>
       <build>
          <plugins>
             <plugin>
                ...
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <forkCount>${forkCount}</forkCount>
                    ...
                 </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
      ...
```

The only references to `forkCount` are included in above.

Everything works as expected if I pass a value for `forkCount` on the command line (i.e., plugin "A" is used when `forkCount` is 0; and plugin "B" is used otherwise).  However, if I run `mvn run_tests`, then plugin "B" gets activated, even though `${forkCount}` has a value of 0.  What's going on?

For what it's worth:

```
>mvn -DforkCount=0 clean verify help:active-profiles
The following profiles are active:
    - no-parallel-execution (source: ....


>mvn clean verify help:active-profiles
The following profiles are active:
  - parallel-execution (source: ....
```

Comment: It is hard to tell here if the issue is the activation, or the plugin configuration that the activation triggers (Which is not seen here) or something else (which is not presented here)  This isn't a complete minimal example, it's a fragment of an example, and might be the wrong fragment for us to discover the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I was trying to rule out any simple/obvious problems before asking people to slog through a long, complex pom file.  I added a more details above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
mvn -DforkCount=0 help:active-profiles
```

to verify that the profiles you really want to be active are active (and the ones you really don't want to be active are not).

-- updating answer to accommodate new information --

Thanks for the updates to the answer, the problem seems pretty clear now.

I believe the issue is that "" is not "0".  With this understanding, this means that "!0" is going to activate on a '' or missing `forkCount` value.

My tests confirm this interpretation.

Perhaps you can redo this, using more profiles. One to detect the condition of the property not being set, and one to detect the conditions of the property being zero.  Both of these profiles might leave an artifact, say a touched file in the $target directory.  Then you might use this file to know you are doing a single-threaded call, and without the file, a multi-threaded call.

Code used to confirm these ideas

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edwinbuck.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-properties</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>unspecified-forkCount</id>
          <activation>
             <property>
               <name>!forkCount</name>
             </property>
          </activation>
      </profile>
      <profile>
          <id>zero-forkCount</id>
          <activation>
             <property>
               <name>forkCount</name>
               <value>0</value>
             </property>
          </activation>
      </profile>
      <profile>
         <id>parallel-execution</id>
         <activation>
            <property>
               <name>forkCount</name>
               <value>!0</value>
            </property>
         </activation>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

command line calls used to confirm these ideas

```
mvn help:active-profiles
mvn -DforkCount=0 help:active-profiles
mvn -DforkCount=3 help:active-profiles
```

results

```
profiles: unspecified-forkCount parallel-execution
profiles: zero-forkCount
profiles: parallel-execution
```

Comment: I added the results to the original post.  The expected profiles appear to be active.

Comment: @Zack I did some testing, and found that "!0" also includes undefined.  After searching for a bit, I can't find a way of stating "greater than zero", so I would create two profiles, one that detects "unset" and one that detects "0" and then try to make the logic to do multi-threaded conditional on some missing element that the two profiles place on disk.